# Windows 11 - Terminal - LaTeX Error - You haven't defined the language [ yet.?

Tags: pdf, unicode, languages, terminal-output, texlive2022

***Code in VSCodium***

```
    \documentclass[
        % remove for less green,
  BCOR=12mm,     % 12mm binding corrections, adjust to fit your binding
  parskip=half,  % new paragraphs start with half line vertical space
  open=any,      % chapters start on both odd and even pages
  cleardoublepage=plain,  % no header/footer on blank pages
]{tudothesis}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{upgreek}
% Warning, if another latex run is needed
\usepackage[aux]{rerunfilecheck}
\usepackage{bibgerm}
% just list chapters and sections in the toc, not subsections or smaller
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%------------------------------ Fonts, Unicode, Language ----------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}  % -- becomes en-dash etc.

% german language
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}

% for english abstract and english titles in the toc
\setotherlanguages{english}

% intelligent quotation marks, language and nesting sensitive
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

% microtypographical features, makes the text look nicer on the small scale
\usepackage{microtype}


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%------------------------ Math Packages and settings --------------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% \let\mtdblcolon\dblcolon
%\usepackage{unicode-math} 
% Enable Unicode-Math and follow the ISO-Standards for typesetting math
\usepackage[
 math-style=ISO,
 bold-style=ISO,
 sans-style=italic,
 nabla=upright,
 partial=upright,
]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
%\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon}]{unicode-math}]

%\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}

% nice, small fracs for the text with \sfrac{}{}
\usepackage{xfrac}
    


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%---------------------------- Numbers and Units -------------------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[
  locale=DE,
  separate-uncertainty=true,
  per-mode=symbol-or-fraction,
]{siunitx}
\sisetup{math-micro=\text{Âµ},text-micro=Âµ}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%-------------------------------- tables  -------------------------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{booktabs}       % \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule, etc

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%-------------------------------- graphics -------------------------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{graphicx}
% currently broken
% \usepackage{grffile}

% allow figures to be placed in the running text by default:
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{htbp}
\floatplacement{table}{htbp}

% keep figures and tables in the section
\usepackage[section, below]{placeins}


%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%---------------------- customize list environments ---------------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{enumitem}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%------------------------------ Bibliographie ---------------------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,   % use modern biber backend
  autolang=hyphen, % load hyphenation rules for if language of bibentry is not
  sorting=none,% german, has to be loaded with \setotherlanguages
  style=numeric-comp,                 % in the references.bib use langid={en} for english sources
]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Literatur.bib}
\def\bibliography#1{}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}  % the bib file to use
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}}}  % replace u.a. with et al.


% Last packages, do not change order or insert new packages after these ones
\usepackage[pdfusetitle, unicode, linkbordercolor=orange]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}



%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%-------------------------    Angaben zur Arbeit   ----------------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\author{vv}
%\title{vvv }
\title{vv \\ \small{vv}}
\date{... Januar 2023}
%\birthplace{vv}
\chair{\small{vv vv}}
\division{\small{vv}}
\thesisclass{vv}
%\firstcorrector{vv}
%\secondcorrector{vv}

% tu logo on top of the titlepage
\titlehead{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{SRH2}}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
%\input{content/hints.tex}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Einleitung}
ABC 
\end{document}
```

***I just had to reinstall LaTeX on my Windows 11 system.
But now I get an error message in the terminal***

```
Package unicode-math Warning: Using \overbracket and \underbracket from 
(unicode-math)                `mathtools' package.  
(unicode-math)  
(unicode-math)                Use \Uoverbracket and \Uunderbracket for  
(unicode-math)                original `unicode-math' definition.

Package unicode-math Warning: I'm going to overwrite the following commands 

(unicode-math)                from the `mathtools' package: 
(unicode-math) 
(unicode-math)                     \dblcolon, \coloneqq, \Coloneqq, \eqqcolon. 
(unicode-math) 
(unicode-math) 
(unicode-math)                 Note that since I won't overwrite the other 
(unicode-math)                colon-like commands, using them will lead to 
(unicode-math)                inconsistencies.

[...]

! You haven't defined the language [ yet. \selectlanguage ...t defined the language #1 yet}
                                                 \else \grmn@originalTeX \e ... l.138 \begin{document}
```

***The LaTeX file runs without errors on my laptop.
I don't know what to do.
Can someone help me with this ?***

Comment: Please provide code and engine information such that others can have an idea as to what exactly you are doing

Comment: Note that the class specified is **not** a well known one, so you might have to specify where to get it as well.

Comment: Why are you loading `bibgerm` (1) it has not been updated since the year 2000, (2) it is related to bibtex, (3) you are using `biblatex`

Comment: Thank you so much! It literally solved my problem. I'm so greatfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `bibgerm` package, which you probably should not. It was last updated in the year 2000, is related to `bibtex` but you're using `biblatex`.

I am assuming the it is just a matter it needing to be loaded later in the document.

**Advice:** make it a habit to write a short comment above each package explaining why this is used. Then if you give the preamble to someone else, they can remove the stuff they don' need.